# Log In to Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

My question is simple - how can I log in to Microsoft Teams? I previously worked for an organization and logged into the web version of Teams (using Google Chrome) using my login credentials for this information.

I have since gone to a new organization. When I try to go to Microsoft Teams (again using Chrome), I always get redirected to the same log in page for the original organization, not the new organization. I am unable to log in with my credentials for the original organization as they have been disabled.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

1. Chrome in incognito mode
2. Another Chrome profile
3. Another web browser
4. Clear the caché and delete the cookies on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by clearing relevant cookies and deleting cached files.

Comment: What website did you remove cookies from?